# Import Developer profile into xcode: certificates greyed out

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been stuck on this for hours..I downloaded the certificate from my developer account, I also downloaded the WWDR intermediate certificate.  When I click Import Developer Profile from inside xcode all of these certificates are greyed out.. Any ideas?

Comment: did you install the Provisioning Profile and change the BundleIdentifier in Plist?

Comment: yup I did both of those things

Comment: I think Bundle Identifier and your provisioning profile Id not match

Comment: Did you select the provisioning profiles in Project which comes after selecting the Project at the left?

Comment: i don'y understand what you mean

Comment: When you select the Project in the Xcode at left side then at the right you will find the Project and Targets.

Comment: Actually got it working, just set the app id to work with all apps for now..must have been a difference with bundle identifier.  Submit it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bundle Identifier and your provisioning profile Id should match . Check that

Comment: how we can change provisioning profile id?

Comment: how is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 8):

You can import Developer profile into Xcode which file have a **.developerprofile** extension which was exported by Xcode. Xcode->Preference->Account->[SETTING ICON]->Export Accounts.

From xcode 6.x, Xcode export ipa only with distribution certificate. So you must have valid distribution certificate install in keychain.

If you setup developer certificate and trying to export then

if distribution certificated is not created in developer portal ,then xcode will automatically create it.

if distribution certificated is already created by other mac , and you have not install in your mac then Xcode will give message **"Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate"** [image]

Then You can either install Distribution certificate by .p12 file exported by keychain from old mac OR by .developerprofile extension. exported by xcode from old mac  OR Revoke Existing Certificate and create new one and install

Then Remove account from xcode and add it again. Then try again to build.

Comment: Hi, I cannot import my .developerprofile into my account on my other mac. I'm an admin in the program, I export my developer account from the first mac and try to import it on my 2nd mac however after I enter my password (created when exporting) I receive  the error: "An unknown error occurred trying to open the file ...developerprofile" Anu ideas?